# eclipse、java8をantでビルドすると「ブートストラップ・クラスパスが-source 8と一緒に設定されていません」とエラーになる

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

表題の通りですが、eclipse初心者過ぎてclasspassの設定方法がわかりません。
現状は以下の構成で、javacは不明。

jdk-14.0.2
jre1.8.0_261
tomcat8.5.57

以下エラー内容です。よろしくお願いします。

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\build-web.xml
clean:
compile:
    [javac] Compiling 41 source files to C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] 警告:[options] ブートストラップ・クラスパスが-source 8と一緒に設定されていません
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\push\CarrierPushServlet.java:18: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.utilは存在しません
    [javac] import jp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.util.MdkMerchantUtility;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\util\CarrierUtility.java:11: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dtoは存在しません
    [javac] import jp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dto.MdkServiceConstants;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\PaymentMethodSelect.java:10: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dtoは存在しません
    [javac] import jp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dto.MdkServiceConstants;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\carrier\base\AbstractAuthorizeExec.java:11: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdkは存在しません
    [javac] import jp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.ITransaction;
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\carrier\base\AbstractAuthorizeExec.java:12: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdkは存在しません
    [javac] import jp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.TransactionFactory;
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\carrier\base\AbstractAuthorizeExec.java:13: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dtoは存在しません
    [javac] import jp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dto.CarrierAuthorizeRequestDto;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\carrier\base\AbstractAuthorizeExec.java:14: エラー: パッケージjp.veritrans.tercerog.mdk.dtoは存在しません
・・・
・・・
・・・
・・・
・・・

    [javac]             ITransaction tran = TransactionFactory.getInstance(reqDto);
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac]   シンボル:   変数 TransactionFactory
    [javac]   場所: クラス AbstractTerminateExec
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\carrier\base\AbstractTerminateExec.java:100: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
    [javac]             CarrierTerminateResponseDto resDto = (CarrierTerminateResponseDto)tran.execute();
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   シンボル:   クラス CarrierTerminateResponseDto
    [javac]   場所: クラス AbstractTerminateExec
    [javac] C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\web\carrier\base\AbstractTerminateExec.java:100: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
    [javac]             CarrierTerminateResponseDto resDto = (CarrierTerminateResponseDto)tran.execute();
    [javac]                                                   ^
    [javac]   シンボル:   クラス CarrierTerminateResponseDto
    [javac]   場所: クラス AbstractTerminateExec
    [javac] 注意:C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\src\jp\veritrans\tercerog\sample\util\Custom.javaの操作は、未チェックまたは安全ではありません。
    [javac] 注意:詳細は、-Xlint:uncheckedオプションを指定して再コンパイルしてください。
    [javac] エラー78個
    [javac] 警告1個

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\build-web.xml:70: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

回答が付かないようなので、あまり詳しくないですが自分がハマった時の回避策をご参考までに書きます。

```
C:\Users\tono\tomcat\pleiades\workspace\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\web\WEB-INF\build-web.xml
```

に

```
<property name="version.target" value="12"/>
<property name="version.source" value="12"/>
```

のような記述がありませんか？

上記はJava12の例ですが、この記述と実際に使用しているSDKのバージョンが合っておらず、必要なライブラリ等が見つからない場合などにエラーが表示されるようです。
このバージョンを合わせてやればエラーを回避できるのではないかと思います。

また、「ブートストラップ・クラスパスが-source 8と一緒に設定されていません」を検索ワードにして検索すると、似たような事例が結構ヒットします。ご自身の環境と近い例を参考に設定を見直されてみてはどうでしょうか。